# Getting error 401 Unauthorised: Missing bearer authentication in header

Tags: api, rest, http, curl, postman

**API Documentation**
This is the documentation for the available API endpoints, which are built around the REST architecture. All the API endpoints will return a JSON response with the standard HTTP response codes and need a Bearer Authentication via an API Key.

**Base url**
https://app.popify.site/api

**Retrieve a user**

```
curl --request GET \
--url 'https://app.popify.site/api/user' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer {api_key}' \
```

Getting error 401: Missing bearer authentication in header, though I'm using correct api key.

Comment: What do you want? fix Curl or postman? Please double check the `bearer token`.

Comment: I want to know why I'm getting error 401 if I'm using correct token. I triple checked everything.

Comment: @lucasnguyen17 - Can you try running the commands from your end? I have created a test account for you and you will have your own API key. Api docs and commands are provided. login at : app.popify.site/login.  email: test4@test.com. Password: 123456

Comment: Can't figure out what's wrong with it. You have to talk to dev.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a JWT token you are passing, I'd suggest you to go to `JWT decode` and paste your encoded token to see what all information it consists. Ideally. roles and user related information is available in payload, if some of it is not enrolled or available on the authorization server, it will result in 401 Unauthorized.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl --request GET \
--url 'https://app.popify.site/api/user' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer {api_key}' \
```

wrap your authorization with quotes and do the same with bearer like this:

```
 --url 'https://app.popify.site/api/user' \
-- header "Authorization ": "Bearer {api key} "
```

using fetch API:

```
const result = async getBalance(){
        
        await fetch("https://foma.line.pm/balance", {
            method: "get",
            headers: {
                "Authorization": " Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIU "
            }}).then(response => response.json()).then(data => console.log(data) 
         ) 
    }
```